# Boost multiprecision rounding mode

Tags: c++, boost, rounding

Is there a way to change the rounding mode used in Boost.Multiprecision?

I want to use this library but need to know if I can specify the rounding mode for arithmetic operations on the fly, such that I can guarantee certain properties of operations (e.g. that they are overapproximating).

Is there a cheap way of knowing whether rounding has happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I found out that Boost::Interval with a custom type can preserve the inclusion property. However this requires implementing all the arithmetic with downwards and upwarts rounded results.
With this in mind I can equip the Boost::Interval with any floating point implementation I like, e.g. mpfr_t. For further details see:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/guide.htm

Comment: I am going to use boost::interval<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int>, have you had any experience with that? Did it work?

Comment: I have not tried this type - from what I've seen so far, you can do as I did and specialize the arithmetic. For me this did work out so far.